# Typescript difference between union types and "indexed tuple" 

Tags: typescript

Is there any difference between these two types?

```
type type1 = [String,Number][number]

type type2 = String | Number

const a: type1 = "";
const b: type1 = 1;

const c: type2 = ""
const d: type2 = 1
```

Comment: No, [they are the same](//tsplay.dev/WYlVbm).  Why are you asking this?  Aside from the various unconventional things happening here (user-defined types are usually written in `UpperPascalCase` not `lowercase`, so `Type1` and `Type2`;  the `String` and `Number` types [are probably not the right ones to use](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object)), why would you create a tuple and then immediately index into it this way?  Without some context it seems unmotivated, like saying `let v = 3 + 5` instead of `let v = 8`.

Comment: ... Could you [edit] to provide some clarifying context so that we can answer in terms of this context?

Comment: I was trying to understand this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708464/convert-schema-to-a-type/76708668#76708668) And he used the first type, so I got curious if it would be different than a union, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference. If you hover over your `type1`, you will see that TypeScript has evaluated it and it has resolved into the union `String | Number`.

You can try it in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBKkIxQLxQNoGVgCcCWA7A5gDQByArgLYBGEmAuirhdXQFAuzQcBMSUGOBKAB8oZKjTYBjAPa4AzsCgBDAFwxwEBMgBE2gNwsZ8xZTUctUOAcOyFUSWY08d2m8agATR5GeWgA)

However, you shouldn't use `String` or `Number` as types in TypeScript. These refer to the `String` and `Number` constructors. Rather, you should use `string` and `number`.

See [this old answer from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727461/1710523) for a more detailed explanation of the difference between `String` and `string`.